# filtering data in python. I can't understand how to work with data or dictionarys or collections or whatever this is, it's a response from an api

Tags: python, dictionary, filtering

I have the following data and I want to filter by operationType and all after a specific operationDate.  I'm coming from a powershell world where this is typically easy

```
$newdata = $data | where-object
{(
   (($_.operationtype -eq "create-order") -and ($_.operationDate -gt $filterdate))
)}
```

I am really struggling to figure out how to do this in python, also are there any tips on just figuring out how to search data and figure how the different data types that are in in object.

```
{'attributes': {'objectType': 'Collection'},
 'items': [{'applicationId': 'XXXXX-0788-4ca7-a3e2-cc042d1fafc1',
            'attributes': {'objectType': 'AuditRecord'},
            'customerId': 'XXXXX-aef9c3736de3',
            'customerName': 'XXXX',
            'customizedData': [{'key': 'SubscriptionId',
                                'value': 'XXXX-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c'},
                               {'key': 'OfferId',
                                'value': 'CFQ7TTC0HDB0:0002:CFQ7TTC0Q3S4'},
                               {'key': 'SubscriptionName',
                                'value': 'Project Plan 3'},
                               {'key': 'Quantity', 'value': '36'},
                               {'key': 'Status', 'value': 'Active'},
                               {'key': 'PartnerOnRecord', 'value': ''},
                               {'key': 'AdditionalPartnersOnRecord',
                                'value': 'None'},
                               {'key': 'ActionTaken', 'value': 'False'},
                               {'key': 'ClientName',
                                'value': 'Partner Center NET SDK'}],
            'id': 'XXXXxx-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c_7808bbb0-2ef7-4175-a824-aef9c3736de3_a8389331-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c_updatesubscription_638461281810210059',
            'operationDate': '2024-03-15T19:36:21.0210059Z',
            'operationStatus': 'succeeded',
            'operationType': 'update_subscription',
            'originalCorrelationId': '93fd8894-53cf-4b4b-bbbd-a305e6cca650',
            'participants': ['XXXXX-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c'],
            'partnerId': 'XXXXX-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c',
            'resourceNewValue': '{"Id":"XXXXX-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c","OfferId":"CFQ7TTC0HDB0:0002:CFQ7TTC0Q3S4","EntitlementId":null,"OfferName":"Project '
                                'Plan 3","FriendlyName":"Project Plan '
                                '3","ProductType":{"Id":"OnlineServicesNCE","DisplayName":"OnlineServicesNCE","SubType":null},"Quantity":36,"UnitType":"Licenses","ParentSubscriptionId":null,"HasPurchasableAddons":false,"ConsumptionType":null,"CreationDate":"2024-01-19T14:34:54.3734661Z","EffectiveStartDate":"2024-01-19T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","CancellationAllowedUntilDate":"2024-01-26T14:35:37.7428362Z","BillingCycleEndDate":"2024-03-31T00:00:00Z","BillingCycleEndDateTime":"2024-03-31T23:59:59Z","Status":"active","AutoRenewEnabled":true,"ScheduledNextTermInstructions":null,"NextChargeInstructions":null,"IsTrial":false,"BillingType":"license","BillingCycle":"monthly","Actions":null,"TermDuration":"P1Y","RenewalTermDuration":"","RefundOptions":null,"IsMicrosoftProduct":true,"PartnerId":"","AdditionalPartnerIds":null,"SuspensionReasons":null,"AttentionNeeded":false,"AttentionReason":null,"ActionTaken":false,"ContractType":"subscription","Links":{"Product":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Sku":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0/skus/0002?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Availability":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0/skus/0002/availabilities/CFQ7TTC0Q3S4?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Self":{"Uri":"/customers/7808bbb0-2ef7-4175-a824-aef9c3736de3/subscriptions/a8389331-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]}},"PublisherName":"Microsoft '
                                'Corporation","PromotionId":null,"MigratedFromSubscriptionId":null,"RefundableQuantity":{"TotalQuantity":10,"Details":[{"Quantity":2,"AllowedUntilDateTime":"2024-03-21T19:01:32.3813585Z"},{"Quantity":8,"AllowedUntilDateTime":"2024-03-21T20:17:07.2106854Z"}]},"LineItems":null,"ProductOrderId":null,"MigratedToSubscriptionId":null,"OrderId":"306fd3e18496","Attributes":{"ObjectType":"Subscription"}}',
            'resourceOldValue': '{"Id":"XXXX-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c","OfferId":"CFQ7TTC0HDB0:0002:CFQ7TTC0Q3S4","EntitlementId":null,"OfferName":"Project '
                                'Plan 3","FriendlyName":"Project Plan '
                                '3","ProductType":{"Id":"OnlineServicesNCE","DisplayName":"OnlineServicesNCE","SubType":null},"Quantity":33,"UnitType":"Licenses","ParentSubscriptionId":null,"HasPurchasableAddons":false,"ConsumptionType":null,"CreationDate":"2024-01-19T14:34:54.3734661Z","EffectiveStartDate":"2024-01-19T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","CancellationAllowedUntilDate":"2024-01-26T14:35:37.7428362Z","BillingCycleEndDate":"2024-03-31T00:00:00Z","BillingCycleEndDateTime":"2024-03-31T23:59:59Z","Status":"active","AutoRenewEnabled":true,"ScheduledNextTermInstructions":null,"NextChargeInstructions":null,"IsTrial":false,"BillingType":"license","BillingCycle":"monthly","Actions":null,"TermDuration":"P1Y","RenewalTermDuration":"","RefundOptions":null,"IsMicrosoftProduct":true,"PartnerId":"","AdditionalPartnerIds":null,"SuspensionReasons":null,"AttentionNeeded":false,"AttentionReason":null,"ActionTaken":false,"ContractType":"subscription","Links":{"Product":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Sku":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0/skus/0002?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Availability":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0HDB0/skus/0002/availabilities/CFQ7TTC0Q3S4?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Self":{"Uri":"/customers/7808bbb0-2ef7-4175-a824-aef9c3736de3/subscriptions/a8389331-731a-4b17-d845-2383aa197a5c","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]}},"PublisherName":"Microsoft '
                                'Corporation","PromotionId":null,"MigratedFromSubscriptionId":null,"RefundableQuantity":{"TotalQuantity":10,"Details":[{"Quantity":2,"AllowedUntilDateTime":"2024-03-21T19:01:32.3813585Z"},{"Quantity":8,"AllowedUntilDateTime":"2024-03-21T20:17:07.2106854Z"}]},"LineItems":null,"ProductOrderId":null,"MigratedToSubscriptionId":null,"OrderId":"306fd3e18496","Attributes":{"ObjectType":"Subscription"}}',
            'resourceType': 'subscription',
            'sessionId': 'XXX-1d06-4247-a5a2-f33ae27f070b',
            'userPrincipalName': 'XX@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com'},
           {'applicationId': 'XXXXXX-0788-4ca7-a3e2-cc042d1fafc1',
            'attributes': {'objectType': 'AuditRecord'},
            'customerId': 'XXXXXX-0798-456d-9410-823ce4b64daf',
            'customerName': 'XXXXXX.com',
            'customizedData': [{'key': 'SubscriptionId',
                                'value': 'XXXX-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654'},
                               {'key': 'OfferId',
                                'value': 'CFQ7TTC0MM8R:0002:CFQ7TTC0KJG8'},
                               {'key': 'SubscriptionName',
                                'value': 'Microsoft Copilot for Microsoft 365'},
                               {'key': 'Quantity', 'value': '4'},
                               {'key': 'Status', 'value': 'Active'},
                               {'key': 'PartnerOnRecord', 'value': ''},
                               {'key': 'AdditionalPartnersOnRecord',
                                'value': 'None'},
                               {'key': 'ActionTaken', 'value': 'False'},
                               {'key': 'ClientName',
                                'value': 'Partner Center NET SDK'}],
            'id': 'XXXXX-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c_212d295f-0798-456d-9410-823ce4b64daf_f695db4c-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654_updatesubscription_638461264103277207',
            'operationDate': '2024-03-15T19:06:50.3277207Z',
            'operationStatus': 'succeeded',
            'operationType': 'update_subscription',
            'originalCorrelationId': '960bb9be-90c7-4a11-9256-d9f8a1d3769f',
            'participants': ['XXX-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c'],
            'partnerId': 'XXXX-09bb-46ad-8562-3d9bf04c4d6c',
            'resourceNewValue': '{"Id":"f695db4c-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654","OfferId":"CFQ7TTC0MM8R:0002:CFQ7TTC0KJG8","EntitlementId":null,"OfferName":"Microsoft '
                                'Copilot for Microsoft '
                                '365","FriendlyName":"Microsoft Copilot for '
                                'Microsoft '
                                '365","ProductType":{"Id":"OnlineServicesNCE","DisplayName":"OnlineServicesNCE","SubType":null},"Quantity":4,"UnitType":"Licenses","ParentSubscriptionId":null,"HasPurchasableAddons":false,"ConsumptionType":null,"CreationDate":"2024-01-26T14:20:04.1872682Z","EffectiveStartDate":"2024-01-26T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","CancellationAllowedUntilDate":"2024-02-02T14:20:51.9610179Z","BillingCycleEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","BillingCycleEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","Status":"active","AutoRenewEnabled":true,"ScheduledNextTermInstructions":null,"NextChargeInstructions":null,"IsTrial":false,"BillingType":"license","BillingCycle":"annual","Actions":null,"TermDuration":"P1Y","RenewalTermDuration":"","RefundOptions":null,"IsMicrosoftProduct":true,"PartnerId":"","AdditionalPartnerIds":null,"SuspensionReasons":null,"AttentionNeeded":false,"AttentionReason":null,"ActionTaken":false,"ContractType":"subscription","Links":{"Product":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Sku":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R/skus/0002?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Availability":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R/skus/0002/availabilities/CFQ7TTC0KJG8?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Self":{"Uri":"/customers/212d295f-0798-456d-9410-823ce4b64daf/subscriptions/f695db4c-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]}},"PublisherName":"Microsoft '
                                'Corporation","PromotionId":null,"MigratedFromSubscriptionId":null,"RefundableQuantity":{"TotalQuantity":0,"Details":[]},"LineItems":null,"ProductOrderId":null,"MigratedToSubscriptionId":null,"OrderId":"XXX","Attributes":{"ObjectType":"Subscription"}}',
            'resourceOldValue': '{"Id":"f695db4c-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654","OfferId":"CFQ7TTC0MM8R:0002:CFQ7TTC0KJG8","EntitlementId":null,"OfferName":"Microsoft '
                                'Copilot for Microsoft '
                                '365","FriendlyName":"Microsoft Copilot for '
                                'Microsoft '
                                '365","ProductType":{"Id":"OnlineServicesNCE","DisplayName":"OnlineServicesNCE","SubType":null},"Quantity":3,"UnitType":"Licenses","ParentSubscriptionId":null,"HasPurchasableAddons":false,"ConsumptionType":null,"CreationDate":"2024-01-26T14:20:04.1872682Z","EffectiveStartDate":"2024-01-26T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","CommitmentEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","CancellationAllowedUntilDate":"2024-02-02T14:20:51.9610179Z","BillingCycleEndDate":"2024-12-31T00:00:00Z","BillingCycleEndDateTime":"2024-12-31T23:59:59Z","Status":"active","AutoRenewEnabled":true,"ScheduledNextTermInstructions":null,"NextChargeInstructions":null,"IsTrial":false,"BillingType":"license","BillingCycle":"annual","Actions":null,"TermDuration":"P1Y","RenewalTermDuration":"","RefundOptions":null,"IsMicrosoftProduct":true,"PartnerId":"","AdditionalPartnerIds":null,"SuspensionReasons":null,"AttentionNeeded":false,"AttentionReason":null,"ActionTaken":false,"ContractType":"subscription","Links":{"Product":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Sku":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R/skus/0002?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Availability":{"Uri":"/products/CFQ7TTC0MM8R/skus/0002/availabilities/CFQ7TTC0KJG8?country=US","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]},"Self":{"Uri":"/customers/212d295f-0798-456d-9410-823ce4b64daf/subscriptions/f695db4c-6783-4954-d2ff-7e427b4a8654","Method":"GET","Body":null,"Headers":[]}},"PublisherName":"Microsoft '
                                'Corporation","PromotionId":null,"MigratedFromSubscriptionId":null,"RefundableQuantity":{"TotalQuantity":0,"Details":[]},"LineItems":null,"ProductOrderId":null,"MigratedToSubscriptionId":null,"OrderId":"XXX","Attributes":{"ObjectType":"Subscription"}}',
            'resourceType': 'subscription',
            'sessionId': 'XXXXX-5201-40fd-b3f4-278ad40882a3',
            'userPrincipalName': 'XXXX@XXXX.onmicrosoft.com'},
           {'applicationId': 'XXXXX-0788-4ca7-a3e2-cc042d1fafc1',
            'attributes': {'objectType': 'AuditRecord'},
            'customerId': 'XXXXXX-7d8e-4458-b009-91d710a877d4',
            'customerName': 'XXXXX',
            'customizedData': [{'key': 'SubscriptionId',
                                'value': 'XXXX-98c6-4c41-c962-1c3a5c89ea44'},
                               {'key': 'OfferId',
                                'value': 'CFQ7TTC0HL8W:0001:CFQ7TTC0QSVC'},
                               {'key': 'SubscriptionName',
                                'value': 'Power BI Premium Per User'},
                               {'key': 'Quantity', 'value': '60'},
                               {'key': 'Status', 'value': 'Active'},
                               {'key': 'PartnerOnRecord', 'value': ''},
                               {'key': 'AdditionalPartnersOnRecord',
                                'value': 'None'},
                               {'key': 'ActionTaken', 'value': 'False'},
                               {'key': 'ClientName',
                                'value': 'Partner Center NET SDK'}],
```

Comment: Try: `items = [item for item in dct["items"] if item["operationType"] == "create-order" and item["operationDate"] > "2024-03-15T19:06:50.3277207Z"]`

Comment: *dict['items'] is not a generic class

Comment: `dct` contains your dictionary you have in your question. It's just variable name.

Comment: These are just nested dictionaries and lists. There are many tutorials on how to work with them in Python, we can't teach you here.